# "umount: /mnt/dev/pts: target is busy" とエラー表示され umount できない

Tags: linux, kernel

Manjaro Linuxがカーネルパニックを起こしたため、chrootを使った手法で修復を試みたのですが、最後の/mntのumountで "umount: /mnt/dev/pts: target is busy" とエラーになりumountできません。

`fuser -v /mnt` で使用状況を確認したところ以下のようになっていました。

```
/mnt    root    kernel mount /mnt
```

現在のディレクトリは `pwd` で確認したところ `/` になっていました。

どうすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`/mnt/dev/pts` は chroot したさきの 仮想端末のデバイスファイルだと思います。
現在使用している 端末画面（黒い画面）が終了すれば busy 状態は解消すると思います。
なので、exitでchrootを終了してから umount /mnt だとどうですか？

```
# exit
# umount /mnt
```